# Drawing a grid filled with pre-defined shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

To draw the progress of a game of Coloraddo, I used the following code
from the answer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628385/drawing-a-square-grid-with-a-default-size-more-than-1).

I noticed that, in the bottom grid drawing, the last 9 uppermost right squares do not display the grid outline!

To overcome this problem, I added the following code.

```
\pic[] at (7*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[] at (7*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[] at (7*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[] at (8*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[] at (8*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[] at (8*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[] at (9*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[] at (9*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[] at (9*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
```

**What is wrong with my code? and how can I fix it!**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=10mm, right=10mm, top=8mm, bottom=15mm}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\begin{document}
%begin defining shapes ==========================
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lwdth}{.5mm}% for line width
\tikzset{%
trg/.style={%
regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw=black, line width=\lwdth, fill=blue, minimum size=1.4cm, rounded corners=0.1cm},
crc/.style={%
circle, draw=black, line width=\lwdth, fill=green!70!black, minimum size=1.cm},
sqr/.style={%
regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4, draw=black, line width=\lwdth, fill=yellow, minimum size=1.2cm},
str/.style={%
star, star points=6, draw=black, line width=\lwdth, fill=red, minimum size=1.1cm},
filrd/.style={%
fill=red},
filgr/.style={%
fill=green},
filyw/.style={%
fill=yellow},
filbl/.style={%
fill=blue},
}
%end defining shapes ==========================
%begin defining grid ==========================
\newcommand\sqw{1}
\tikzset{
pics/square/.default={\sqw},
pics/square/.style = {
code = {
\draw[pic actions] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);
}}}   
\renewcommand\sqw{1.3}
%end defining grid ==========================
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3, transform shape]
\draw[step=\sqw] (\sqw,\sqw) grid (7*\sqw, 7*\sqw);
%col1
\node[str] at (1.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (1.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col2
\node[sqr] at (2.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (2.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filrd] at (2*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (2*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (2*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col3
\node[crc] at (3.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (3.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (3.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
\pic[filrd] at (3*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (3*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (3*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col4
\pic[filyw] at (4*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (4*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (4*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (4*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (4*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (4*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col5
\pic[filyw] at (5*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (5*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (5*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (5*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (5*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (5*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col6
\pic[filyw] at (6*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (6*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (6*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (6*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (6*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (6*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col7
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col8
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col9
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip .4cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3, transform shape]
\draw[step=\sqw] (\sqw,\sqw) grid (7*\sqw, 7*\sqw);
%col1
\node[str] at (1.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (1.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col2
\node[sqr] at (2.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (2.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filrd] at (2*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (2*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (2*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col3
\node[crc] at (3.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (3.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (3.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
\pic[filrd] at (3*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (3*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (3*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col4
\node[crc] at (4.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (4.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (4.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
\pic[filbl] at (4*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (4*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (4*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col5
\node[crc] at (5.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filbl] at (5*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (5*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (5*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col6
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filbl] at (6*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (6*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (6*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col7
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col8
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col9
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip .4cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3, transform shape]
\draw[step=\sqw] (\sqw,\sqw) grid (7*\sqw, 7*\sqw);
%col1
\node[str] at (1.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (1.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col2
\node[sqr] at (2.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (2.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filrd] at (2*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (2*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (2*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col3
\node[crc] at (3.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (3.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (3.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
\pic[filrd] at (3*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (3*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filrd] at (3*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col4
\node[crc] at (4.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (4.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (4.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (4.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (4.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (4.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col5
\node[crc] at (5.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col6
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (6.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col7
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col8
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col9
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip .4cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3, transform shape]
\draw[step=\sqw] (\sqw,\sqw) grid (7*\sqw, 7*\sqw);
%col1
\node[str] at (1.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (1.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col2
\node[sqr] at (2.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (2.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (2.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col3
\node[crc] at (3.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (3.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (3.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (3.5*\sqw,3.4*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (3.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (3.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col4
\node[crc] at (4.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (4.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (4.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (4.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (4.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (4.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col5
\node[crc] at (5.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col6
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (6.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col7
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (7*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col8
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (8*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col9
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,5*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filbl] at (9*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip .4cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3, transform shape]
\draw[step=\sqw] (\sqw,\sqw) grid (7*\sqw, 7*\sqw);
%col1
\node[str] at (1.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (1.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col2
\node[sqr] at (2.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (2.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (2.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col3
\node[crc] at (3.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (3.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (3.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (3.5*\sqw,3.4*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (3.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (3.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col4
\node[crc] at (4.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (4.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[trg] at (4.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (4.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (4.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (4.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col5
\node[crc] at (5.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col6
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (6.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
%col7
\node[crc] at (7.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (7.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[crc] at (7.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col8
\node[crc] at (8.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (8.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (8.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
%col9
\node[crc] at (9.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
\node[sqr] at (9.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
\node[str] at (9.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
\pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use the `grid` drawing command to draw all of the grid lines in a single command?

Comment: @– Andrew Stacey This is just a part of a more complicated drawing. Anyway how can I follow your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the last grid. (Actually, the others too: the colored **framed** squares hide the fact that the entire 9x6 grid is not drawn.)

[image: a]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3, transform shape]
        \draw[step=\sqw] (\sqw,\sqw) grid (10*\sqw, 7*\sqw); % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
        %col1
        \node[str] at (1.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[trg] at (1.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (1.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
        %col2
        \node[sqr] at (2.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[trg] at (2.5*\sqw,5.4*\sqw) {};
        \node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[crc] at (2.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (2.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
        %col3
        \node[crc] at (3.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[str] at (3.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[trg] at (3.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
        \node[trg] at (3.5*\sqw,3.4*\sqw) {};
        \node[crc] at (3.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (3.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
        %col4
        \node[crc] at (4.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[str] at (4.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[trg] at (4.5*\sqw,4.4*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (4.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[str] at (4.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (4.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
        %col5
        \node[crc] at (5.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[str] at (5.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
        %col6
        \node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[str] at (6.5*\sqw,2.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[crc] at (6.5*\sqw,1.5*\sqw) {};
        %col7
        \node[crc] at (7.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[crc] at (7.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[crc] at (7.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
        \pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
        \pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
        \pic[filyw] at (7*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
        %col8
        \node[crc] at (8.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (8.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (8.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
        \pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
        \pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
        \pic[filyw] at (8*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
        %col9
        \node[crc] at (9.5*\sqw,6.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[sqr] at (9.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {};
        \node[str] at (9.5*\sqw,4.5*\sqw) {};
        \pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,3*\sqw) {square};
        \pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,2*\sqw) {square};
        \pic[filyw] at (9*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Why is this needed in this particular drawing, and not for the other ones!

Comment: @Hany Do the same with the other grids. The colored **framed** squares hide the fact that the entire 9x6 grid  is not drawn.

Comment: @– Simon Dispa Thank you.