# Inserting a dice-simulation code in different locations

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I use the following code from the answers to
[this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629717/drawing-dice-simulation), and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628385/drawing-a-square-grid-with-a-default-size-more-than-1) to insert dice-simulation code in different locations.

**How can I put the dice code in a style to be inserted in different locations in the grid!**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
%begin defining shapes ==========================
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lwdth}{.3mm}% for line width
\tikzset{%
filrd/.style={%
fill=red},
filgr/.style={%
fill=green},
filyw/.style={%
fill=yellow},
filbl/.style={%
fill=blue},
}
%end defining shapes ==========================
%begin defining grid ==========================
\newcommand\sqw{1}
\tikzset{
pics/square/.default={\sqw},
pics/square/.style = {
code = {
\draw[pic actions, draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);
}}}%draw=none is to avoid displaying the little squares outline

\renewcommand\sqw{1.3}
%end defining grid ==========================

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\dice}[5]{
\tdplotsetmaincoords{#3}{#4}
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1,#2)}, tdplot_main_coords, rounded corners=#5, fill=brown!30!white]
%bottom face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!30!white, fill=brown!30!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
%left face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=-1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!30!white, fill=brown!30!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
%back face
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=-1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!30!white, fill=brown!30!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
%top face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!30!white, fill=brown!30!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[green!70!black] circle[radius=2/3];
\end{scope}
%right face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!50!white, fill=brown!50!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[blue] circle[radius=2/3];
\end{scope}
%front face
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!40!white, fill=brown!40!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[red] circle[radius=2/3];
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
}
\dice{0}{0}{40}{130}{0.3cm};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]
\draw[step=\sqw] (\sqw,\sqw) grid (2*\sqw, 10*\sqw);
\pic[filbl] at (1*\sqw,9*\sqw) {square};
\node at (1.5*\sqw,8.5*\sqw) {\Huge insert dice here};
\pic[filgr] at (1*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\node at (1.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {\Huge insert dice here};
\pic[filgr] at (1*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\node at (1.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {\Huge insert dice here};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left image puts the dice into a savebox and put the saveboxes into nodes.  The right image uses a different `\dice` for each location.

I modified `\dice` to make named coordinates easier and to add a scale factor.  However, the current version cannot handle large rotations accurately.  See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295585/cube-in-tikz-not-drawn-correctly-possibly-a-bug-in-tikz/295604?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C16.4462#295604)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\newsavebox{\tempboxA}
\newcommand{\dice}[5]{% #1=shift coordinates, #2=scale, #3,#4=view angles, #5=rounded coner radius
\tdplotsetmaincoords{#3}{#4}
\begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},scale=#2, tdplot_main_coords, rounded corners=#5, fill=brown!30!white]
%bottom face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!30!white, fill=brown!30!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
%left face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=-1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!30!white, fill=brown!30!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
%back face
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=-1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!30!white, fill=brown!30!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{scope}
%top face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!30!white, fill=brown!30!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[green!70!black] circle[radius=2/3];
\end{scope}
%right face
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!50!white, fill=brown!50!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[blue] circle[radius=2/3];
\end{scope}
%front face
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=1]
\filldraw[draw=brown!40!white, fill=brown!40!white] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[red] circle[radius=2/3];
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
%begin defining shapes ==========================
\pgfmathsetmacro{\lwdth}{.3mm}% for line width
\tikzset{%
filrd/.style={%
fill=red},
filgr/.style={%
fill=green},
filyw/.style={%
fill=yellow},
filbl/.style={%
fill=blue},
}
%end defining shapes ==========================
%begin defining grid ==========================
\newcommand\sqw{1}
\tikzset{
pics/square/.default={\sqw},
pics/square/.style = {
code = {
\draw[pic actions, draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);
}}}%draw=none is to avoid displaying the little squares outline

\renewcommand\sqw{1.3}
%end defining grid ==========================

\savebox{\tempboxA}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \dice{(0,0)}{0.4}{40}{130}{0.3cm};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]
\draw[step=\sqw] (\sqw,\sqw) grid (2*\sqw, 10*\sqw);
\pic[filbl] at (1*\sqw,9*\sqw) {square};
\node at (1.5*\sqw,8.5*\sqw) {\usebox\tempboxA};
\pic[filgr] at (1*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\node at (1.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw) {\usebox\tempboxA};
\pic[filgr] at (1*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\node at (1.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw) {\usebox\tempboxA};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, transform shape]
\draw[step=\sqw] (\sqw,\sqw) grid (2*\sqw, 10*\sqw);
\pic[filbl] at (1*\sqw,9*\sqw) {square};
\dice{(1.5*\sqw,8.5*\sqw)}{0.4}{40}{130}{0.3cm};
\pic[filgr] at (1*\sqw,6*\sqw) {square};
\dice{(1.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw)}{0.4}{40}{130}{0.3cm};
\pic[filgr] at (1*\sqw,4*\sqw) {square};
\dice{(1.5*\sqw,3.5*\sqw)}{0.4}{40}{130}{0.3cm};
\pic[filrd] at (1*\sqw,1*\sqw) {square};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to add to your code a background colour [, background rectangle/.style={fill=violet!90!white}, show background rectangle, rounded corners=1.cm].  How and where can I insert it?

Comment: This is what I have in mind https://i.stack.imgur.com/E910a.png
I could add the background colour when using \node[scale=.5, fill=gray!80!white] at (1.5*\sqw,8.5*\sqw) {\usebox\tempboxA};
But I could not add it when using \dice{(1.5*\sqw,5.5*\sqw)}.       Could the background colour option be added to the original \newsavebox{\tempboxA} code!

Comment: Just add a normal \pic **before** \dice.  The only difference between background and foreground is the order in which they are drawn.

Comment: @– John Kormylo Thank you. But it will be easier to  include the background colour option in the original \newsavebox{\tempboxA} code! to avoid repeating putting \pic before every \dice!